# Will my query works without two dimension array in if else or not

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I have confusion since I was looking inside and try to solve the problem.  I have `PHP` application which is running in `Oracle DB` and so far some expression is written in MySQL and right now I want to migrate those query to `Oracle SQL` function and call function insted of writing query directly to model.
The situation is following
I have function line

```
public function getAtaNumber($data) {

    if( $data["Type"] == 1 ) {
    
        $sql = "SELECT SUM(NextNumber) + 1 AS NextNumber 
                FROM (
                        SELECT COUNT(a1.ATAID)  AS NextNumber 
                        FROM ata AS a1 
                        WHERE a1.ProjectID = '".$data["project"]["id"]."' 
                        AND a1.Ata = 1 
                        AND a1.ParentAta = 0 
                        AND a1.TYPE = 1 
                        AND a1.BecomeExternalAtaFromInternal = 0 
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT COUNT(a2.ATAID)  AS NextNumber 
                        FROM ata AS a2 
                        WHERE a2.ProjectID = '".$data["project"]["id"]."' 
                        AND a2.Ata = 1 
                        AND a2.ParentAta = 0 
                        AND a2.BecomeExternalAtaFromInternal = 1 ) AS A";
    
    } else {
    
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ata.ATAID) + 1 AS NextNumber 
                FROM ata 
                WHERE ProjectID = '".$data["project"]["id"]."' 
                AND Ata = 1 
                AND ParentAta = 0 
                AND Type = 0 
                ORDER BY ATAID DESC 
                LIMIT 1;";
    
        if (!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
            error_log($conn->error);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This if make me confusion and I have no idea how to write this peace of code. Since I  run SELECT statment both of them and it return correct result, but I have no idea what to do with this `IF`
Since this is two dimension array and I have no idea how to write it in `PLSQL Oracle SQL`
When I run the first SELECT statment

```
SELECT SUM(NextNumber) + 1 AS NextNumber 
FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(a1.ATAID)  AS NextNumber 
        FROM ata a1 
        WHERE a1.ProjectID = 137 
        AND a1.Ata = 1 
        AND a1.ParentAta = 0 
        AND a1.TYPE = 1 
        AND a1.BecomeExternalAtaFromInternal = 0 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(a2.ATAID)  AS NextNumber 
        FROM ata  a2
        WHERE a2.ProjectID = 137 
        AND a2.Ata = 1 
        AND a2.ParentAta = 0 
        AND a2.BecomeExternalAtaFromInternal = 1 
    )  A

NEXTNUMBER
18
```

And When I run second SELECT query

```
SELECT COUNT(ata.ATAID) + 1 AS NextNumber 
FROM ata 
WHERE ProjectID = 137 
AND Ata = 1 
AND ParentAta = 0 
AND Type = 0 
ORDER BY ATAID DESC ; 



NEXTNUMBER
        1
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this two dimension array problem in `PLSQL Oracle SQL` or Does even this kind of array exist in `Oracle SQL` ?
Just one notation I also try something like

```
IF(data"Type"==1)
    SELECT
ELSE 
    SELECT
```

Also

```
IF(data'Type'=1)
    SELECT
ELSE 
    SELECT
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Why I get downvotes ? 
What part of code do you mean ?

Comment: I think you will have to leave the `if( $data["Type"] == 1 ) {` in PHP code and then call the correct Proceedure (I assume you are saying you want to write an Oracle Proceedure) from PHP. Or are you trying to replace PHP completely

Comment: I want to write this part of code in Oracle SQL as function not Procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function which returns the next ATA Number for a given PROJECT_ID and TYPE.

```
create or replace function get_ata_number (
    p_project_id in number
   ,p_type       in number
) return number as
   
  l_NextNumber number;

begin  

  if p_type = 1 then

    SELECT SUM(NextNumber) + 1 
    into l_NextNumber
    FROM (
          SELECT COUNT(a1.ATAID)  AS NextNumber 
          FROM ata AS a1 
          WHERE a1.ProjectID = p_project_id
          AND a1.Ata = 1 
          AND a1.ParentAta = 0 
          AND a1.TYPE = 1 
          AND a1.BecomeExternalAtaFromInternal = 0 
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNT(a2.ATAID)  AS NextNumber 
          FROM ata AS a2 
          WHERE a2.ProjectID = p_project_id
          AND a2.Ata = 1 
          AND a2.ParentAta = 0 
          AND a2.BecomeExternalAtaFromInternal = 1 );
    
   else 

     SELECT COUNT(ata.ATAID) + 1 
     into l_NextNumber
     FROM ata 
     WHERE ProjectID = p_project_id
     AND Ata = 1 
     AND ParentAta = 0 
     AND Type = 0 ;

  end if;

  return l_NextNumber;
  
end get_ata_number;
```

Note my assumption about the data type of PROJECT_ID, and correct it if necessary.